# Use of Perfect tense

Tags: tense

> 1.Many biologists **have** attempted to simulate the conditions on earth before life **evolved** in order to answer questions about the origin of biological molecules.

I found the above sentence but It seems wrong to me . I perfer to say-

> Either 2. Many biologists **have** attempted to simulate the conditions on earth before life **evolves** in order to answer questions about the origin of biological molecules.
>
> Or 3. Many biologists **had** attempted to simulate the conditions on earth before life **evolved** in order to answer questions about the origin of biological molecules.

Actually which one is right?

Answer (score 2):

The correct version is

> **have** attempted

since they attempted in the past and are still trying to do so

> before life **evolved**

since the evolution already occurred in the past, and you are presumably talking about *the moment life occurred*, not its continual evolution.

The original sentence is correct

> 1.Many biologists **have** attempted to simulate the conditions on earth before life **evolved** in order to answer questions about the origin of biological molecules.